# "Transformar" um elemento em outro com JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

No meu script, tenho um `iframe`.

```
<iframe id="result" name="result" src="url_do_documento" sandbox="allow-same-origin"></iframe>
```

O arquivo q o `iframe` faz referência, contém um elemento `h1`, como na estrutura abaixo:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <h1 class="pf-change-h1">H1 que pretendo alterar!!</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

para acessar o h1, estou utilizando JQuery da seguinte forma:

```
$("#result").load(function(){
    var h1 = $("#result").contents().find(".pf-change-h1");
    h1.click(function(){
        $(this).replaceWith("<input type='text' value='" + $(this).html()  + "' class='pf-change-h1' />");
    });
    /*h1.blur(function(){
        $(this).replaceWith("<h1 class='pf-change-h1' >" + $(this).html()  + "</h1>");
    });*/
});
```

A finalidade deste código seria substituir o elemento `h1` por um `input`, para que seu valor pudesse ser alterado, depois de alterado deveria acontecer exatamente o inverso.

O código comentado é o que justamente não está funcionando, o evento `onBlur` não é disparado e o `input` não é substituído pelo `h1`.

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como fazer essa substituição de elementos?

**UPDATE:**

Tentei ambas as formas das respostas e não obtive o resultado esperado :/

Ao visualizar a execução do código pelo console do navegador, o h1 tem um evento atrelado à ele, como podem ver:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas ao substituir pelo input, este não tem evento nenhum atrelado, fazendo com que não aconteça nada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Essa iFrame está no mesmo domínio?

Comment: Sim, no mesmo domínio

Comment: Mesmo o input contendo a mesma classe do h1?

Comment: Se você puder usar o atributo contentEditable talvez você possa editar o h1 sem ter que transformá-lo em input.

Comment: Tá perdendo a referência do objeto. Edit: acabaram de responder isso :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acho que o problema aqui é que estás a re-escrever o h1, e perdes a referência quando o substituis... a solução que me ocorre é defenires esse novo elemento antes para teres como o referenciar. Sugiro também usares delegação para isso. Nesse caso ficaria assim:

```
$("#result").load(function(){
    var blur = function () {
        $(this).replaceWith("<h1 class='pf-change-h1' >" + this.value + "</h1>");
    }
    $("#result").contents().on('click', ".pf-change-h1", function () {
        var input = $("<input type='text' value='" + ($(this).html() || this.value) + "' class='pf-change-h1' />");
        $(this).replaceWith(input);
        input.focus().blur(blur);
    });
});
```

### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8L8xee69/

Repara que substituí `$(this).html()` para `this.value`, o mesmo que `$(this).val()`, pois elementos input não têm `innerHTML`

Comment: Testarei as duas formas, dependendo do resultado, comentarei aqui, obrigado!

Comment: @Thomerson começa pela segunda (delegando) é a melhor.

Comment: tentei a primeira, obtive o mesmo resultado do meu script, o evento click funciona, mas o blur não. E a segunda não executou nenhum :x pela delegação, o script adiciona os eventos aos elementos de classe ".pg-change-h1" dentro do iframe?

Comment: @Thomerson aha... ok. Esse novo elemento tem de ser criado dentro do contexto da iFrame. Não sei como é que o jQuery trata isso, só sei em JS puro, mas vou editar a resposta.

Comment: Valeu cara, a segunda opção, à pouco editada, funcionou perfeitamente, Obrigado!! xD

Comment: @Thomerson, pois tirei mesmo a outra que tinha problemas. Juntei também um jsFiddle. Fico contente de ter ajudado...

Answer (score 1):

O que acontece é que o `replaceWith` destrói o elemento, e por isso o evento é perdido. É necessário então re-associar os eventos com o elemento. Como você esta trabalhando com um `iframe`, não sei como fica o escopo, mas a idéia é mais ou menos a seguinte:

```
function h1_click() {
    $(this).replaceWith("<input type='text' value='" + $(this).html() + "' class='pf-change-h1' />");
    $(".pf-change-h1").blur(function () {
        $(this).replaceWith("<h1 class='pf-change-h1' >" + $(this).val()  + "</h1>");
    });
    $(".pf-change-h1").click(h1_click());
};

("#result").load(function(){
    var h1 = $("#result").contents().find(".pf-change-h1");
    h1.click(h1_click);
});
```